# Is browser caching of images good enough to invalidate the need for server side storing?

Tags: caching, architecture, browser-cache

I had an architecture question, and I had to rewrite the question title multiple times, since SO asked  me to. So please feel free to correct it, if you feel so. I am not an expert in cache related things so I would very much appreciate some insights about my architecture related question.

So the situation is like this. We have a web based design app (frontend Javascript, backend PHP) which presents lots of clipart images to our customers who use that in creating online art work. Earlier, our app was loaded into an AWS machine and we used to have the clipart images also stored locally in the same server in order to not have any network transfer required to load the clipart and thus make the design app load time faster. The customer created designs were also saved into a backend MySQL server connected directly to the web based design app (in JSON and relational model).

A while before a new team joined to make a mobile version of this app, and they insisted that the cliparts should be loaded from a "central location" both for our web app, and for the mobile app they are creating. They also said that the design should also be stored into a "central database", accessible by the web and mobile apps (and there were some major re-architecting of the JSON structure as well)

So finally, the architecture changed such that, the cliparts now reside in a centralized location (S3 Server). And there is an "Asset Delivery and Storage (ADS) System" to which our design app makes requests for clipart images and gets served. (Please note that the cliparts repository is very large and only a subset of clipart images are served based on various parameters - such as the style of the design, account type of the customer etc).  So this task is now done by the ADS system (written in python).

And since our web design app no longer has any local storage of cliparts nor logic of cliparts filtering (which got delegated to ADS, so no more server side PHP), it has also become a purely web based (front end Javasdcript) app without any server requirements and subsequently got moved to S3.

Now the real matter is that, our web app seems much more slower when initial loading, than when we had our on stash of cliparts stored in the server. I read that if an app requests for images, those images are cached in the browser and if the customer, for eg, loads the same order before that cache has expired then there is no repeat request that needs to be sent to the server (in this case ADS).

If that is true, is there any case I can really make to state that moving the clipart images from the design app server to the ADS system and having to send a request and load them every time a design is loaded has contributed in part to the recent slowness of the design app?

Also most times I hear the answer that "mobile app also does the same and is faster".I am not a mobile developer. Could there be some mobile cache tricks that help the mobile app to be much more "cache-efficient" than the purely web based design app, such that even though the architecture is same for both (sending request ADS for cliparts), the mobile app does it in a better and more efficient manner?

End note:  I realise I am not asking a specific programming question. But from some of the notes I have read here, SO is a community for  programmers, and I do not know of any other community that so well answers programming related questions. The architecture question I have is a genuine programming related question I face at work and sadly I am not skilled enough to understand if all the recent architectural changes there has any drawbacks that is causing our web app performance to degrade noticeably.

Thanks for reading, and I would really appreciate any pointers or even links to reading for better understanding this.

Comment: You will have to run profilers to figure out exactly what part of the system is slow. All modern browsers have profilers.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, open up the developer tools, and click on the network tab.  90% of the time you can identify the slow resource from there.